# Error calling Instantiate in Unity on WP?

Tags: windows-phone, instantiation

```
GameObject obj = (GameObject) Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Actions/" + actions, typeof (GameObject)));
```

No problem with other platforms. But, when building on Windows Phone:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: I suspect the `/` in your path, as Windows directories use \. Try to avoid hardcoding paths by referencing to prefabs you want to instantiate via a field in the editor.

Comment: I've done that. but it can not solve the problem. Other solutions???